# Where can I find information on the architecture, dataflow, scheduling, protocols supported etc.? of ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am searching for information on the architecture, dataflow, scheduling, protocols supported etc. of ROS. I am thus looking for information/data sheet/document containing detailed information on the aspects requested previously. Does any one know where this information can be found or in which collection of documents it can be found? Any advice/information will be greatly appretiated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9185/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-architecture,-dataflow,-scheduling,-protocols-supported-etc.?-of-ros/) by [ReZist](https://answers.ros.org/users/179/rezist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the [technical overview of ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2